# Skyrim-enb crash to desktop

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods

I've been trying to install enbs on skyrim for a while now. However, when I try to use Realvision's installer I get some error about a missing file and it fails to install. When I try to manually install a different enb, it seems to work until I load a save, after which it crashes to the desktop.

I have also tried editing the video memory usage in the enb's ini file, with no success. Enbs has worked before but I had to reinstall my game and haven't worked since.

What can I do to get it to work?

Comment: A lot of the ENB mods out there require a VERY specific version of the ENB System to be installed. I use Seasons of Skyrim for example and it lists the lists the specific version it is compatible with and requires in its installation steps. I am not sure about Realvisions installer though so can not advise you in its use.

Comment: Did you run RV_launcher.exe in Data\RealVision_ENB_files and click install?